# Where is <div class="col-left sidebar"> located

Tags: layered-navigation, column

on my site I have

> div class="col-left"

and it should be

> div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first"

For some reason I change it in the 3columns.phtml and it sill doesn't seem to be showing on the site when I view source. I've reset cache on magento and my browser. Is the  located in any other part of the directory besides 3columns.phtml

Comment: Turn on template path hints, to see what's loaded in your template.

Answer (score 3):

Its either in

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/3columns.phtml

or

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/2columns-left.phtml

Make sure that you update correct file -- if you change base/default (which is considered a bad practice) and you have copy of it in {package}/{theme} folder then your changes is not taken into consideration.

Also I'm not sure what you plan to achieve with `col-left-first` as this div is considered wrapper for text-list, a container if you will:

```
<div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
```

You probably want to add this class to blocks inside that div.

Answer (score 1):

Layered navigation is added via XML. Check your catalog.xml. To move something from "col-left" to "col-left-first", you will want to put it the "left_first" section instead of just "left" for example

```
    <reference name="left_first">
         <block type="catsidebarnav/catsidebarnav" name="left.catsidebarnav" before="-">
            <action method="leftSidebarBlock" />
         </block>
    </reference>
```